# adding new option to dropdown list without refreshing

Tags: php

I have a dynamic dropdown list which gets its value from `tblSupplies`. The administrator may add a new option to the dropdown list. I was able to make this but it requires the admin to go to another page to add an option, this results to the formerly inputted values to be erased. Here is the code for my dynamic dropdown list

```
<select name="Supply_Name" id="Supply_Name">
                                <?php
do {  ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['Supply_ID']?>"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Supply_Name']?></option>
                                <?php} while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
if($rows > 0) {
  mysql_data_seek($Recordset1, 0);
  $row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1); }
?>
                            </select>
```

Comment: try ajax and you should be good to go

Answer (score 0):

ajax would be the way to go here. can send the data to a php page in the background and then when its done reload only the div with the dropdown menu in it.

more on [ajax and jquery here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

and more on [js and ajax here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)